# Could not find goal '' in plugin org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, liquibase

подключаю новый проект из удаленного репозитория

в терминале пишу: mvn liquibase: update

Получаю:

```
[ERROR] Could not find goal '' in plugin org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.1 among available goals dropAll, rollback, clearCheckSums, updateTestingRollback, changelogSync, updateSQL, migrateSQL, generateChangeLog, dbDoc, status, listLocks, changelogSyncSQL, releaseLocks, migrate, tag, diff, rollbackSQL, futureRollbackSQL, update, help -> [Help 1]
```

pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>data/db.changelog-dev.xml</changeLogFile>
                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</url>
                <username>postgres</username>
                <password>postgres</password>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

пробовал добавлять зависимость

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
<artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

также не помогло добавление библиотеки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

mvn liquibase: update
пробел не нужен